# rsync "Operation not supported" errors for ACL on ZFS

Tags: debian, rsync, access-control-list, openzfs

While migrating our file server to a ZFS file system with `rsync -avxHAXS ...` I get errors like:

```
rsync: [generator] set_acl: sys_acl_set_file(path/to/file, ACL_TYPE_ACCESS): Operation not supported (95)
```

I've already configured ZFS ACL settings with:

```
zfs set aclmode=passthrough aclinherit=passthrough pool/home
```

Apparently this error can occur in rsync 3.2.3 (https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/109), but upgrading to the patched 3.2.4 did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

After much searching, I found the answer at https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/rsync-set_acl-sys_acl_set_file-archiv-acl_type_default-operation-not-supported-95.25543/.  The following ZFS setting fixes the issue:

```
zfs set acltype=posixacl pool/home
```